# Wunderground Full Screen zoom

Tags: full-screen

I really like Wunderground's new [Full Screen](http://www.fullscreenweather.com/) feature. It's especially nice when using the browser's F11 full screen option.

How can I make the view zoomed out farther automatically when the map is initially loaded? I like to see a broader view so I can be aware of approaching weather.

The [WunderMap](http://www.wunderground.com/wundermap/) is another feature of theirs I really like. It makes a link to the current view available which includes a zoom level in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can add the same zoom information to the query string of the Full Screen URL. Just append something like `&zoom=7` at the end of the query string.

For example:

```
http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?brand=wxmap&query=35.123456,-90.987654&zoom=7
```